# Adding icon to Flex color picker

Tags: apache-flex, components, color-picker

I want to add an icon to the color picker component which will have the value of no color (a blank rectangle) . is ther a way to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can make image's of whatever you'd like as icon.

Right mouse button the src map - new - CSS file to create a new CSS file in your source map, or where you want it.

Double click the CSS file and go to design mode. Right mouse button on the stage or press the +style button on the top of the contentfield.

choose your component (colorpicker) - change the color in the right column, if you still can't get what you want press the skin button in the right column and select "image files" from the list and insert your images.

In short:
- make images of what you want
- make css file
- add css to the colorpicker component
- choose skin from right menu
- choose image files from the list
- insert the images you made

ow and don't forget to add your css file in the application.